# Three.js how to make text that goes through object?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Subj. How to achieve perspective 3D text goes through another object in the scene? Text background should be transparent.

[image]

Bonus question: how do I turn that text into animated ticker?

I've tried CSS3DRenderer, but can't make text background transparent:
[image]

Comment: _” Bonus question: how do I turn that text into animated ticker?”_ What do you mean by this?

Comment: He meant [marquee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) in old tongue referring to ticker tape, or is marquee now the old one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach with [TextGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/geometries/TextGeometry) would need VertexShader knowledges, and would be a wrong end, in terms of rendering cost and "fine quality" of rendering.

I believe this [example](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/codrops-kinetic-typo/) illustrate what you want to achieve but might be a little bit overkill, but the tutorial and code are [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2020/06/02/kinetic-typography-with-three-js/) (a library used is outdated [three-bm-font](https://github.com/Experience-Monks/three-bmfont-text), i'm working on an [ES6 adaptation](https://github.com/trinketmage/three-glyph)).

If you need a simpler approach and explanation:

- Get an image with text with transparent background (that you generate via photoshop, or, render inside your context to a texture - [3) in doc](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-text));
- You use this image as [Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture) on a mesh material as [map](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Material#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.map) (make sure the material is transparent);
- "Animated ticker" is reference historically as [marquee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) in web context. To achieve that from there, you can play with the [offset](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.offset) of your Texture and make sure [wrapS](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture.wrapS) and [wrapT](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture.wrapT) are set properly.

Comment: ty! got the expected result with plane geometry & texture, tuning it on :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by using Three.js's text geometry. It is a bit more complicated to use than a `BoxGeometry()` or `SphereGeometry()`, but the docs and examples are going to be helpful. See the links below...

Docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/geometries/TextGeometry

Example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text

Tutorials: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/threejs/threejs_creating_text.htm

> Note: You can always check the source code of all [Three.js examples.](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes) Search for what you want there on the docs and check the code.